# node.js http request lock-up after 5 requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have some very simple code like this:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    hostname: 'google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/'
};

function makeRequest() {
    http.get(options, function(res) {
        console.log('Got response code: ', res.statusCode);
        process.nextTick(makeRequest);
    }).on('error', function(err) {
            console.error('Got error: ', err);
            throw err;
        });
}

makeRequest();
```

and after 5 requests, it locks up and stops working. Sample output:

```
Got response code:  200
Got response code:  200
Got response code:  200
Got response code:  200
Got response code:  200
Got error:  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

Comment: How often are you hitting up `google.com`?

Comment: Nothing to do with google.com, it happens on all servers -- including my localhost

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets (testable with `agent:false` probably)

Comment: @Wrikken well spotted.

Comment: @Wrikken So how do I close the request, so the socket can be reused / closed?

Comment: @Heptic: if you click the link provided, and scroll up a few lines, it says it there. See also the description of `http.request`. Keep in mind that servers themselves may limit to max concurrent connections they'll allow from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [hyperquest README](https://github.com/substack/hyperquest), which explains exactly what is happening here, why @substack hates it, and how hyperquest can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

By default client connections are pooled and have a 2 min idle timeout and default maximum pool size of 5.

If you are not going to reuse the instanced agent, you should call destroy() method after using it and avoid keeping idle connection in pool.
Example:

```
var req = http.request({path: "/", host: "google.com",method: "HEAD"})
req.end();
req.on("response",function(res) {
    //do something
    // ....
    req.destroy();         
    //do other things
});
```